# Python how to generate all pair-terms

Tags: python, algorithm, generator

I want an infinite generator of all "pair-terms". Where `0` is pair-term and a tuple `(a,b)` of two pair-terms is a pair term. It's only important that each item appears at least once (in a finite amount of time), but exactly once would be more efficient.

I came up with

```py
def pairTerms():
  yield 0
  generated=[]
  diagonal=-1 #sum indices in generated of the pairs we are generating, could be replaced by len(generated)-1
  for t in pairTerms():
    generated.append(t)
    diagonal+=1
    for i,a in enumerate(generated):
      yield (a,generated[diagonal-i])
```

But this quickly fills up the memory.
EDIT: this approach actually seems to work good enough, generating over 10 million terms before fulling up the memory.

Alternatively:

```py
def pairTermsDepth(depth):   
  yield 0 
  if depth:
      for a in pairTermsDepth(depth-1):
        for b in pairTermsDepth(depth-1):
          yield (a,b)

def pairTerms():
  i=0
  while True:
    for item in pairTermsDepth(i):
      i+=1
      yield item
```

But this has the disadvantage of re-listing all old terms when a new while iteration has been reached and exhausting the stack.

Note: I didn't quite know how to tag this question, feel free to change them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following approach can find the first 100 million terms in half a minute on my computer (printing them will take longer), and the memory usage for generating the first `N` terms is `O(sqrt(N))`.

```
def pair_terms() :
    yield 0

    # By delaying this recursion until after a yield, we avoid
    # an infinite recursive loop.
    generated = []
    generator = pair_terms()
    this = generator.next()

    while True:
        for j in range(len(generated)):
            yield (this, generated[j])
            yield (generated[j], this)
        yield (this, this)
        generated.append(this)
        this = generator.next()
```

The trick is that to produce the `n`'th term, I only need to keep a record of terms up to `sqrt(n)`.  I do that by having the generator call itself recursively.  That seems like extra work, but since you're only making `O(sqrt(n))` recursive calls, the overhead of the recursive calls is a rounding error compared to generating results.

Answer (score 2):

If you care more about memory than speed you can also try listing them by length, as such:

```
def pairTermsLength(L):
  if L == 1:
    yield 0 
  else:
    for k in range(1,L//2+1):
      for a in pairTermsLength(k):
        if L-k != k:
          for b in pairTermsLength(L-k):
            yield(a,b)
            yield(b,a)
        else:
          for b in pairTermsLength(L-k):
            yield(a,b)

def pairTerms():
  L = 1
  while True:
    for p in pairTermsLength(L):
      yield p
    L += 1
```

This will use memory and recursion depth linear to the length (in number of 0's) of the longest pair-term generated. The number of pair-terms of length `n` is the `n-th` [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number), which grows exponentially with `n`, so the memory consumption is `O(log(n))`. To give you an idea, for a length of 30 you are already in 10^16 territory, which is probably way more than you have time for anyway, even with a faster algorithm.

Comment: One correction.  The number of pair-terms of length n+1 should be the n'th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) which grows exponentially.